# symfony3 installation of asseticBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, assetic

i'm trying to Install assetic bundle  but when the installation is done ,fosuserbundle is removing i tried to réinstalle It but an exception occured "The child node "from_email" at path "fos_user" must be configured."
can any one help me please??

Answer (score 0):

You probably misconfigured your YAML files. Check the indentation and the inclusions of all your configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter your code like this...

```
fos_user:
     db_driver: orm 
     firewall_name: main
     user_class: App\UserBundle\Entity\User
     from_email:
              address:        app@yoursite.com
              sender_name:    Your App Admin
```